# TeamCity - Behind Proxy causing build failure

Tags: proxy, nuget, teamcity, nuspec

Below is an error message I am getting trying to build a current project, 
I am behind an enterprise proxy but this has only happened this morning after building fine for the past couple of months.

the current installed version of nuget is 2.8.3 and nuspec is 3.0.0.

I see it says it needs credentials but this has never happened before and i am not sure how to get around this in Teamcity.

Also all my other solutions are building fine so it makes it even more confusing as they are all built on the same template.

[image: Failue Stack]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if I were less impatient and did some back tracking on my check-ins, I would have noticed that I had checked in .nuget/packages.config. which had dependencies on these packages above.

I removed these from the .nuget/packages.config and this resolved the issue.

Hope if anyone in the future is having the similar issues that this will help you too.